# What does this variable mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> “A variable so related to another that for each value assumed by one there is a value determined for the other.” ([thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/function))

I can’t find any possible way how to start with this words. I’d like to say what I don’t know at least, but only to fail to do so. I hope to be got the right parse and its meaning.

Comment: The meaning of *function* in this case should has the same meaning as one in this example: *The degree of drought is largely a function of temperature and drainage.* And *variable* in the original sentence means *a quantity that may assume any one of a set of values*. The original sentence's construction should be "a variable so ... that ...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that, like most dictionary definitions, this is not a complete sentence. To make it a complete sentence, we can read it as "[A function is] a variable so related...".

Second, note that the noun "variable" is implied in the prepositional phrase beginning with *to*, and in a few other places thereafter:

> A variable so related to another [variable]...

Third, I think you may be getting tripped up by the adverb [*so*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/so), which is used in a nonintuitive way in this definition. It is used here in the sense of "in such a way" or "in the manner indicated":

> A variable [that is] related to another [in such a way] that for each value assumed by one there is a value determined for the other.

This is roughly the same sense in which you use the word yourself: "...only to fail to do so."

The reason it's confusing here is that although the word "related" is being used here as a verb in the past tense, "related" can be used as an adjective as well. And when we see the construction "[noun] ([verb]) *so* [adjective]," the word *so* is usually used in a different sense--that of an [intensifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensifier) indicating a greatness of degree:

> ...a man *so* old his hair was as white as snow.

Knowing all this, we can rewrite the definition in a way that may be clearer to you:

> [A function is] a variable [that is] related to another [variable] [in such a way] that for each value assumed by one [variable] there is a value determined for the other [variable].